# A way to get all combinations of multiple strings(Python)

Tags: python, list

Say I put in:

```
["abc", "def"]
```

it would give me:

```
["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]
```

The code I used:

```
combs = [""]
conv = {"2":"abc","3":"def","4":"ghi","5":"jkl","6":"mno","7":"qprs","8":"tuv","9":"vxyz"}
for digit in "23":
    for comb in combs:
        for loop in range(len(conv.get(digit))):
            combs.append(digit)
```

But this code creates an infinite loop

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.product`

Comment: provide your code for checking

Comment: @Barmer Yes the solution posted by Burning Alcohol used itertools.product, I didn't know itertools had a function for a problem like this

Comment: @sourab maity I edited in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
a = ["abc", "def", "hk"]
b = ["".join(s) for s in itertools.product(*a)]
print(b)
```

output: `['adh', 'adk', 'aeh', 'aek', 'afh', 'afk', 'bdh', 'bdk', 'beh', 'bek', 'bfh', 'bfk', 'cdh', 'cdk', 'ceh', 'cek', 'cfh', 'cfk']`

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
a = product('abc','def')
print(list(a))
```

Comment: this will print list of tuples